# Multithreaded GridView updates

Tags: c#

Here, I am using simple logic in C#. I am subtracting days from two `DateTimePicker`s and generating the same number of `GridView` rows as total days. I put this logic in a `Timer`, which ticks at an interval of 100 milliseconds and executes automatically. This works fine for 90-100 rows, but if it goes to 1000 rows, then the program gets stuck. So, I am thinking I need to use threads. How can I do this? I know basic multithreading, and tried this, which didn't work:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMethod();
}

void myMethod() {
    ed_Picker.MinDate = sd_Picker.Value;
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();

    //GridView.Rows.cont

    label3.Text = ed_Picker.Value.CompareTo(sd_Picker.Value).ToString();
    //dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    ts = ed_Picker.Value.Subtract(sd_Picker.Value);
    double d;

    d = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays) + 1;
    label3.Text = d.ToString();
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();


    GridView.RowCount = Int32.Parse(d.ToString()); // This is key line which I like to put in new Thread
    for (int i = 1; i <= GridView.RowCount; i++)
    {
        GridView.Rows[i - 1].Cells[0].Value = sd_Picker.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(i - 1)).ToLongDateString();
        GridView.Rows[i - 1].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
    }
    DateTimeConverter dtc = new DateTimeConverter();
    TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView.RowCount; i++)
        {
            ts1 += Convert.ToDateTime(GridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(GridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    label6.Text = ts1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The story helps us understand the plot. Either way, you should probably read about BackgroundWorkers [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: ok, I want to create new thread So, that even if there are 10K rows, it want disturb to main program, and run behind the scene.

Comment: @YoryeNathan : I tried to use Bcakgroundworkers, but getting same error : "InvalidOperationException -  Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ed_Picker' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." this error getting on first line of myMethod Method.

Comment: Why did you write it in Timer.Tick? In which line does it generates error? Try writing that line in:   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { write that line here; }));

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea of how to use BackgroundWorker to do thread work and update the UI:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerReportsProgress = true};
worker.DoWork += this.ThreadWorkMethod;
worker.ProgressChanged += this.ThreadProgressMethod;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

...

private void ThreadWorkMethod(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i = 1000; i++)
    {
        // Time consuming operation
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        worker.ReportProgress(i * 100d / 1000, i);
    }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you can access controls, etc.

    if (e.Progresspercentage == 100)
    {
        this.progLabel.Text = "100% Done";
    }
    else
    {
        this.progLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}% ({1} / 1000)",
                                            e.ProgressPercentage,
                                            e.UserState);
    }
}
```

And if you want to listen to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event as well - you can also access controls from there, etc.

So the DoWork method is all about doing the hard thread work, and calling ReportProgress so it can change the UI appropriately, whenever the need comes. The RunWorkerCompleted event will be called automatically when the DoWork method is done (returns or finishes).